# Images will only load in debug, but not when it is run outside of debug Java

Tags: java, image, filepath

I'm trying to figure out how and why my images will only load in debug in NetBeans, but yet when I execute the JAR file it will fail to load the images. I have tried debugging the code to fix issue within the path, but any altered statements has no effect on it.

Below is code that is generating the issue.

```
String imagePath = getClass().getResource("/StandardDeck/GameCards/"+ toString() +".png").getPath();
```

When doing a file.exists() it always returns false.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you added `StandardDeck` folder in your jar class path?

Comment: Yes. StandardDeck is a package (found in src) that contains class files. in a subfolder had GameCards which has all the images of my cards.

Comment: Now check the same inside your exported `jar` if you are only exporting class files then these folders will get removed.

Comment: Nope the subfolder is in there, along with all the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method won't work once the application is packaged into a JAR file. You won't access image inside a JAR with `java.io.File` class.

You need to use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
InputStream imageStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/StandardDeck/GameCards/"+ toString() +".png");
```

To start working with the image try:

```
ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(imageStream);
```

Comment: So I'm supposed to use an InputStream and read it in bytes and then draw it?

Comment: Yes. Use InputStream and do whatever you need. Paste more code - what are you doing now with the File?

Comment: Right now I'm researching InputStream and ImageInputStream. I've not used it before.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did some googling on it and saw how another person loaded their image using an ImageIcon, using the stuff you provided. That was what I was looking for. Thank you much!